# Variable from a class to another class

Tags: php, class

I'm not very expert in PHP.

I have two classes in two different files.

class_Functions.php

```
<?php
class Functions {
    [...]
    public static function Get_Config($section,$key) {
        $config_file = 'config/config.ini';
        if (isset($config_data)) {
            unset($config_data);
        }
        $config_data = parse_ini_file($config_file, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
        return $config_data[$section][$key];
    }
    [...]
}
?>
```

class_PDO.php

```
<?php
Class Connection {

    private $server = "mysql:host=XXX;port=YYY;dbname=ZZZ";
    private $user = "AAA";
    private $pass = "BBB";
    private $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    protected $con;

    public function openConnection() {
        try {
            $this->con = new PDO($this->server, $this->user,$this->pass,$this->options);
            return $this->con;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public function closeConnection() {
        $this->con = null;
    }
}
?>
```

I need to replace XXX, YYY, ZZZ, AAA and BBB in the second class with variables which values are as follow:

XXX -> $XXX = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'host');

YYY -> $YYY = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'port');

ZZZ -> $ZZZ = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'db_name');

AAA -> $AAA = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'username');

BBB -> $BBB = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'password');

Comment: ...and what problem are you having, specifically? It's a bit unclear what the question or issue is - "I need" isn't a question and doesn't define a problem. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: How can I set XXX, YYY, ZZZ, AAA and BBB as php variables, which values are defined through the first class?

Comment: To define variables, you just...define them. And then you can populate them by calling the function at an appropriate time...just like any other class variable, such as the ones you've already created in your class (`$con`, for example). It's not clear what the problem is or why you're stuck with that. e.g. https://3v4l.org/U4806 - I assume this is the kind of thing you need.

Comment: If you fixed your problem, please add it as an Answer below, for the benefit of yourself (to get upvotes) and the rest of the community (who may find the solution useful in future). Solutions added in the comments cannot be voted on or found in searches - instead your question will appear to remain un-answered. Please take the [tour] if you're unfamiliar with how Stackoverflow's Question and Answer format works. And also you can read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) from the help centre. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've fix my problem editing the second class as follow:

```
Class Connection {
    protected $con;
    public function openConnection() {
        try {
            $this->server = "mysql:host=".Functions::Get_Config('DB','host').";port=".Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'port').";dbname=".Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'name');
            $this->user = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'username');
            $this->pass = Functions::Get_Config('DB', 'password');
            $this->options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->con = new PDO($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->options);
            return $this->con;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public function closeConnection() {
        $this->con = null;
    }
}
```